# gerrit: why gerrit automatically submit a merge commit

Tags: git, gerrit

I received a change in gerrit, after code review, I submitted it. The commit can be seen in git:
[image]

That's quite normal. But after about **4 minutes**, the gerrit automatically submitted a merge submit...

[image]

The committer is not me, and the merge change cannot be seen in the gerrit history. It can only be seen from git log history. This merge submit is about 4 minutes(1566465692-1566465442=250s) after the parent submit

Why there is the merge submit automatically and it's about 250 seconds late?

Comment: 1) Are you really sure that the commit was already visible for you *on the target branch*? I'm asking because a 'git show' can show a commit if you have it locally for some reason (e.g. on another branch, downloaded manually using git-fetch, etc.). 2) It's by design that the time on the authored commit is the same as in the change (local from the author workstation, time may not be in sync with you or the Gerrit server!), but the merge commit will take the time of submission. Are you saying that the commit also *appeared* later for you (in between fetches)?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your project is configured with "Submit Type = Always Merge":

**Always Merge**

Always produce a merge commit, even if the change is a strict superset of the destination branch. This is identical to the behavior of git merge --no-ff, and may be useful if the project needs to follow submits with git log --first-parent.

See more info about the submit types in the Gerrit documentation [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-project-config.html#submit-type).

Comment: This answer does not address the question about why this happens 250 seconds after Gerrit submitted the change without a merge commit and already appeared on the target branch.

Comment: Acctually the merge was commited 250 seconds after the previous commit was done. The 1566465692 is the timestamp of the commit and not the submit timestamp. Probably the commit was done, then pushed to Gerrit, then reviewed and finally (250 seconds after) submitted.